# Get array from a array by key javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello ~ I have an array object

```
[ 
  { "name":"mark", "age" : 18 },
  { "name" : "lin" ,"age": 20 }
]
```

I want to transform the over array object to it below .

```
[
 { "name": "mark"},
 { "name" : "lin" }
]
```

Do everyone have any brief method to transform it. thanks ~

Comment: You can iterate the array and call `delete objectReference.age` for each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var array = [ 
  { "name":"mark", "age" : 18 },
  { "name" : "lin" ,"age": 20 }
];

var transformedArray = array.map(function(obj){
    return { name: obj.name };
});
```

Note that `map` returns a new array instead of mutating the original array, which is helpful if you don't want to lose the age information.

Answer (score 2):

Use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```js
var a=[ 
       { "name":"mark", "age" : 18 },
       { "name" : "lin" ,"age": 20 }
      ];
    
for(each in a){
   delete a[each].age
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript `map` function like this snippet below:

```js
var arr = [ 
  { "name": "mark", "age": 18 },
  { "name": "lin", "age": 20 }
];

console.log(arr);

var mappedArr = arr.map(element => {
  return {"name": element.name};
});

console.log(mappedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [ 
  { "name":"mark", "age" : 18 },
  { "name" : "lin" ,"age": 20 }
]

arrayA = array.map((object) => {
  return { name: object.name };
});

// or

arrayB = array.map((object) => {
  delete object.age;
  return object;
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hecubohaho/edit?js,console)